# Dialog and loading file in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to display my text file on clicking continue button when dialog appears. This is how far i have done. When i click "Continue" button it isn't showing any text in dialog.
My text file is saved on desktop.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void OnLoad(View v) {



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Please read carefully!");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.news);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            try {
                FileInputStream fin =openFileInput("bloodline.txt");
                InputStreamReader insr = new InputStreamReader(fin);

                int i = 0;
                String str = "";

                while ((i = insr.read()) != -1) {
                    str = str + (char) i;
                }

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " " + str,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not available " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "File Not available " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IO Exception " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }
    );

    builder.setNegativeButton("Declined", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have declined",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are showing some text in toast message.you haven't set the text in dialog with custom layout.

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. I mean how to set dialog with custom layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you just go through some of these links that I'm listing below,then you'll have the basic idea of how to create dialog depending upon your needs.

[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html): Which is a nice example from android.developer's site and recommended.

[Link 2:](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDialogs/article.html) Popular android tutorials from Vogella

[Link 3](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/): This link will be explaining you to create Custom Dialogs.

[Link 4](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html): Overview of creating dialog from android developers

[Link 5:](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/) From AndroidHive

I hope this will help you a lot.